# Asterisk (p*) in Atom Text editor

Tags: html, atom-editor, paragraph

I may be overlooking something really simple.
I'm currently watching a tutorial about web development, and in the tutorial the guy creates 30 paragraphs by typing p*30 into atom, and I think he presses enter.

I've searched around but I can't find anything on it - and the tutor assumes that this is common knowledge because he doesn't mention any packages or special keys that he presses.

He gets 30 times `<p></p>`

Thanks in advance.
Ray

Comment: ... I keep trying to say he gets 30 times "<p> </p>" but apparently that creates a new paragraph in the question field here, too.

Comment: check [emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) in vs code, should be the same in atom

Comment: Try pressing `tab`: https://atom.io/packages/emmet

Comment: tab works! thanks justinas

Answer (score 0):

had to get emmet
https://atom.io/packages/emmet

then p*30 tab

that did it

cheers!